# React Instantsearch — Set the search string of the SearchBox

Tags: reactjs, react-instantsearch

I'm setting up React Instantsearch but because of SEO features I want to listen to a query string on pageload and then set it in the SearchBox. I've tried all the examples in documentation but I can't get it work.

The only way I can control the state of the SearchBox is through the queryHook but using that I can't set the query on pageload — only whenever the SearchBox is being modified.

My code looks like this right now.
I want to set the "search" variable to be set on pageload if there is an query parameter available.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/lite';
import {
    InstantSearch,
    InfiniteHits,
    SearchBox,
    Configure,
} from 'react-instantsearch-hooks-web';

export default function Search({ location }) {
    const [search, setSearch] = React.useState("")
    const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);

    const searchClient = algoliasearch(
        '...',
        '...'
    );

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const searchTerm = params.get("searchTerm");
        if (searchTerm?.length > 0) setSearch(searchTerm)
    }, [params])

    return (
        <>
            <Layout>
                <div id="Contact">
                    <div className="contactWrapper">
                        <section className="section">
                            <div className="searchWrapper">
                                <InstantSearch
                                    indexName="All Pages"
                                    searchClient={searchClient}
                                >
                                    <div className="searchFieldWrapper">
                                        <Configure hitsPerPage={20} />
                                        <SearchBox 
                                            placeholder={"Vad söker du?"} 
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="searchResultWrapper">
                                        <InfiniteHits hitComponent={Hit} />
                                    </div>
                                </InstantSearch>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Layout>
        </>
    )
}

function Hit(props) {
    return (
        <div className="box">
            <Link to={props.hit.url}>
                <div className="image">
                    <img src={props.hit.image} alt={props.hit.name} />
                </div>
                <div className="title">
                    {props.hit.title.split(" | ")[0].split(" - ")[0].split(" — ")[0]}
                </div>
            </Link>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Trying to use defaultRefinement={"Test"} dont work

Comment: Using connectSearchBox just gives me the error (0 , react_instantsearch_hooks_web__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.connectSearchBox) is not a function